# Python Error: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, database

Trying to read a CSV and save information to a MySQL-database.
I get several errors:

- ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
- AttributeError: 'MySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'rollback'

Which I think i connected to:

- cursor.executemany(sql_insert,records)
- cursor.commit();
- cursor.rollback()

import mysql.connector as sql_db
import pypyodbc as odbc
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import csv

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Python Scripts\Databases\Testfiles\test.csv',sep=";")
columns = ['Id', 'Name', 'Url', 'ImageUrl', 'MaxNumberOfRooms', 'MinNumberOfRooms', 'MaxArea', 'MaxPrice']
df_data = df[columns]
records = df_data.values.tolist()

mydb = sql_db.connect(
      host="127.0.0.1",
      user="Admin",
      password="AdminPassword",
      database="dbTest"
    )

sql_insert = """
    INSERT INTO TestTable
    VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
"""

try:
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(sql_insert,records)
    mydb.commit();
except Exception as e:
    mydb.rollback()
    print(str(e[1]))
finally:
    cursor.close()
    mydb.close()
```

Comment: `commit` and `rollback` are attributes of `connection`s, not `cursor`s.  The parameter substitution placeholder for MySQL connectors is usually `%s`, not `?`.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I updated the question (and my code) with your information. I got a new error then "DatabaseError: Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1". Feels like it should be connected to my database. My first column is "Id" which is INT and autoincrement. Shall i keep that but add another column for my ID in the CSV?

Comment: If you want to insert specific columns then the SQL must look like `INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2....) VALUES (%s, %s,...)```` and the number of columns specified and the number of %s must match.

Comment: ok, thanks, and "col1" in this case, is that the position or the name of the column? And second question, if I use %s, do i then have to format the database column to be "varchar(255)" or can it still be INT, or do INT in the database require that I use %d?

Comment: finally i got i to work, thanks @snakecharmerb

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,GETDATE(), Name, Url, ImageUrl, MaxNumberOfRooms, MinNumberOfRooms, MaxArea, MaxPrice) Name, Url etc. being your variables.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).